# sql server query how to select price from childtable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables 1 product and 1 variant table. A product can have 1 or more variants. I am trying to construct a query to select each products name and their price. The price is stored not in the producttable but in the variants table. The prices for each variant are the same which is the price of a product. These are the tables:

```
USE [test]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[variants](
    [variantid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [productid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [price] [decimal](18, 0) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[variants] ([variantid], [productid], [price]) VALUES (1, 1, CAST(10 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
INSERT [dbo].[variants] ([variantid], [productid], [price]) VALUES (2, 1, CAST(10 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
INSERT [dbo].[variants] ([variantid], [productid], [price]) VALUES (3, 2, CAST(12 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
INSERT [dbo].[variants] ([variantid], [productid], [price]) VALUES (3, 2, CAST(2 AS Decimal(18, 0)))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[products](
    [productid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[products] ([productid], [name]) VALUES (1, N'glove')
INSERT [dbo].[products] ([productid], [name]) VALUES (2, N'tie')
INSERT [dbo].[products] ([productid], [name]) VALUES (3, N'pants')
```

I tried to query it like this:

```
select v.price,p.name,* from dbo.products p
join variants v on v.productid=p.productid
where p.productid=1
```

But then it returns all the variants for productid=1, how can I 'extract' the price from just 1 variant to list this price in my query, so that it only returns 1 row for productid=1?

Comment: if you need only one column from variants column which is price then you can use subquery as well as you are doing only for one product

Comment: You need to give us/SQL Server the *rules* you want to apply to select a specific row from `variants`. I.e. should it be the lowest price? The highest? Something else? I note you've also commented to an answer that there is an additional column to select from `variants`. It would help to have that included in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `v.price` is always the same, then you can `GROUP` by it:

```
select v.price, p.name from dbo.products p
join variants v on v.productid=p.productid
where p.productid=1
group by v.price, p.name
```

Every field you're selecting in the `SELECT` clause must be either included in the `GROUP BY` or an aggregate (`MIN`, `AVG`, etc).

Comment: what if you want to select another column from the variants table that is not the same?

Comment: If you group by a column, and that column has two different values, then you'll have two rows. If you only want one row, you need to somehow instruct SQL server which of the two values you want to use. You can do this with aggregates. `SELECT p.name, v.price, MIN(v.id)` for instance. If you select the aggregate of a field, you should *not* include the field in the `GROUP BY` clause.